# Strike Through in Side by Side Views

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, diff

Removing the red strike though of the red text on red background in side by side views would improve readability.

[image]

From https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3702973

Even with markdown:

[image]

From https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3703057

Comment: No idea what you mean. Can you provide a screenshot i.e.

Comment: [It already exists](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zvRMg.png). (just click "markdown")

Comment: The strike through help to see what was changed, for me removing it will reduce readability (of the diff), not improve it.

Comment: The strike through is good, but the colors could be improved.

Comment: The strike through effects readability in general. Having red vs. green is good enough.

Comment: What would it look like to color-blind people if you remove the non-color cue?

Comment: @Gilles Nice objection - seems colors and strike through are no good

Answer (score 2):

I came here to make this exact suggestion. I agree that having a non-color based cue for colorblind people is a good thing. However, red-green colorblindness affects only [7-10% of men](http://www.colour-blindness.com/general/prevalence/) (and apparently 0% of women, so 3.5-5% of the population at large). I consider it good design to optimize the user experience for the most common users and use cases, while adding extra features to support the edge cases.

<sub>Admittedly, I might feel differently if I weren't an utterly typical 1st-world privileged (dare I say) *dude*. I'm a white, American male with no disabilities... I don't mean to offend anyone by calling them an edge case.</sub>

So rather than just preaching from a soapbox, I thought I'd offer an improvement. You can add this user stylesheet to your browser to remove strikethrough from just the side-by-side editing view.

```
.post-text span.diff-delete {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Chrome doesn't appear to offer a user specific stylesheet ([anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome)), so I had to use the extension [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) to pull this off. Regardless, I like the improvement and I encourage the SE devs to find a way to provide this feature.